# Apache2: allow call of ajax to .php file in restricted directory

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I have restricted directory "includes" by this code in .htaccess file in same directory

```
<Directory>
    Order Deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

And I have a sub-directory "orders" that contains a PHP file. This is listening ajax petitions from client. I tried to add this code to the .htaccess file to allow access from client, but it doesn't woked.

```
<Files /orders/filter_orders_ajax.php>
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Here is paint screen for a better understanding.
Left on the buttom u can see .htaccess of "includes" directory.

[image]

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .htaccess could you use file permissions to restrict the directories that you need restricted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ditch the `<Directory>` containers, the nature of htaccess takes care of that for you. Add simple this to the htacces file in you **includes** directory:

```
Order Deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
```

Then add this to the htaccess file in your **orders** subdirectory:

```
<Files "filter_orders_ajax.php">
  Order Deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
```